# Is it possible to do a multipriority consumer in ActiveMQ JMS?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

**Background**

I'm running a processing server which uses ActiveMQ to hold a job queue.  When running, I'd like to have a worker continue to run jobs same type of job (it's cheap to stay at a type, but expensive to switch), but switch types if jobs of another type are ignored.

Two simple cases:

1. Jobs are waiting on the queue.  When a worker becomes available, it should choose the job of the type that was just processed and fallback to any job if no job matches.
2. Workers are waiting.  When a new job is added, it should be given to a worker that had just processed that job type and fallback to any worker if no such worker is available.

**Example**

My attempt right now simplifies things with prefetch=0, and each worker has two consumers at different priority levels.  I poll the high-priority one once and then block for the low-priority one.

Messages are just the jobId (the details are in a DB) with a property for the type of the job:

```java
public void put(String jobId, String type) {
    jmsTemplate.send(session -> {
        TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(jobId);
        textMessage.setStringProperty("type", type);
        return textMessage;
    });
}
```

Whenever a worker starts a new type of job, it sets up two consumers with different `consumer.priority`s

```java
MessageConsumer consumer = null;
MessageConsumer defaultConsumer = null;

void onResourcesChange(String type) throws JMSException {
    stopConsumers();
    if (type != null) {
        consumer = session.createConsumer(createConsumer(2), "type = '" + type + "'");
    }
    defaultConsumer = session.createConsumer(createConsumer(1));
}

private Destination createConsumer(int consumerPriority) throws JMSException {
    return jmsTemplate.getDestinationResolver().resolveDestinationName(session,
            queueName + "?consumer.prefetchSize=0&consumer.priority=" + consumerPriority.priority, false);
}
```

And then when it is idle, it receives messages in a loop:

```java
while (!shutdown) {
    Message nextMessage = null;
    if (consumer != null) {
        nextMessage = consumer.receiveNoWait(100);
    }

    if (nextMessage == null) {
        if (defaultConsumer != null) {
            nextMessage = defaultConsumer.receive();
        }
    }
    // do something with the message
}
```

**Question**

Is there a way to listen for job messages with a matching type, with a fallback to any?

For instance, can you have the prefetch limit shared between the two consumers -- and get the messages that are a better match until there aren't any?

Or is there a way to express both in the same selector?  Perhaps with age instead of priority?

```
priority1(type = 'type') || priority2(type != 'type')
```

```
type = 'type' || age > 5min
```

Comment: Thank you!  I reorganized and simplified a bunch, with a TL;DR; question.  I may have simplified it to the point that the answer to "can I do this?" is "no" though.

Comment: I'm talking about consumer priority (http://activemq.apache.org/consumer-priority.html), which is an activemq extension.  Message priority is certainly part of the grander scheme of things, but orthogonal to this.

Comment: Good point, thank you.  That's me not quite knowing how to ask the question.  I've updated those sentences.